# Read text file and get its file name in Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

Read text file and get its file name in Batch

I tried below. I am getting content but not file name.

```
type *.txt > newfile.txt
for %f in (*.txt) do type "%f" >> output.txt
```

Output file has contents from multiple files

```
12
324
3243
45
5645
6
```

Expected output is:

```
Filename1.txt
12
324
3243
Filename2.txt
45
5645
Filename2.txt
6
```

**[Edit /]**
It appears that the expected output, *(yet to be confirmed)* is really:

```
Filename1.txt
12
324
3243
```

```
Filename2.txt
45
5645
```

```
Filename2.txt
6
```

Comment: Both of these are giving content only.
for %f in (*.txt) do type "%f" >> output.txt

type .txt > newfile.txt

Comment: Your question is unclear, it would be better were you to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58757076/edit) it, to show us what you want as your file content. Perhaps, `@"%__AppDir__%find.exe" /V "" "*.txt">"output.txt"` will be sufficient for your needs. *If you don't like the `output.txt` line at the top of `output.txt`, just save the file to a different directory, don't use `.txt` as the extension for your output, or use `"path\*.txt"` instead.*

Comment: I see you've edited your question to provide some important information. Thank you for that, I've now edited it so that we can read it. Now as my comment above provides advice which produces a similar output, can you please provide appropriate feedback, and I'm sure that @BenPersonic would appreciate a similar courtesy. If you're going to just type it at the command line, and haven't messed with `%PATH%`, you could probably shorten the command to `find /V "" *.txt>output.txt`.

Comment: Thanks @compo for the details. I could not get the result what i was looking for. Instead, i followed another way where i added filename into first lie of each text file and then did the type *.txt > output.txt 

Below is the command I used to add filename into first line of each text file


for %%I in (*.txt) do (
    echo %%~nI>"%TEMP%\FileName.tmp"
    echo/>>"%TEMP%\FileName.tmp"
    copy /B "%TEMP%\FileName.tmp" + "%%~I" "%%~I.tmp">nul
    del "%%~I"
    ren "%%~I.tmp" "%%~nxI"
)
del "%TEMP%\FileName.tmp" 2>nul

Comment: SKumar, that does not produce the expected output as defined in your question. Your expected output is clearly one file, `output.txt` containing each `.txt` filename followed by its content. All you've done is to prepend the content of each file with its current name and a blank line. It's a little unfair to post your solution, given that it answers a different question, one that you simply didn't post.

Answer (score 1):

`type` has an unexpected habit: it writes the file names to STDERR, but the file's contents to STDOUT. If you want to redirect *both* to a file, you need to redirect both STDOUT (`>`) and STDERR (`2>&1` = "to the same destination as STDOUT"):

```
type *.txt >newfile.tmp 2>&1
move /y newfile.tmp newfile.txt
```

Naming the destination file `.txt` results in being typed too (the resulting file will contain two copies of some of your files). Therefore I redirect to a `.tmp` file and rename it later.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something like this:

```
for %_ in (
 "C:\Folder\*.txt"
) do (
  ECHO=
  ECHO==============================================
  ECHO== Begin File: %~nx_
  ECHO==============================================
  ECHO=/---------------------------------------------\
  type "%~f_"
  ECHO=\---------------------------------------------/
  ECHO=
) >> "C:\SomeFolder\output.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the result what i was looking for. Instead, i followed another way where i added filename into first lie of each text file and then

```
type *.txt > output.txt
```

Below is the command I used to add filename into first line of each text file

```
for %%I in (*.txt) do (echo %%~nI>"%TEMP%\FileName.tmp"
    echo/>>"%TEMP%\FileName.tmp"
     copy /B "%TEMP%\FileName.tmp" + "%%~I" "%%~I.tmp">nul
  del "%%~I"    ren "%%~I.tmp" "%%~nxI")
del "%TEMP%\FileName.tmp" 2>nul
```